# discord.js trying to set slash command permissions

Tags: javascript, permissions, discord.js, command

I am trying to set permissions for my slash commands. I am using discord.js v13.

```
defaultPermission: false
        })
        .then((c) => {
            const permissions = [
                {
                    id: '689468223728779323',
                    type: 'ROLE',
                    permission: true
                },
                {
                    id: '346001113914408976',
                    type: 'USER',
                    permission: true
                }
            ]

            c.permissions.add({ permissions })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit slash command permissions anymore as a Bot. You have to (as a user using the discord client) go to `Server Settings` > `Integrations` > `Your application` > `Manage`

[image: discord developer]